# How to use binding relativesource in style

Tags: wpf, data-binding, relativesource

Using the default style

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}"x:Key="HeaderStyleS">
    <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, 
            Path=Content.DataContext.ViewName}" />
</Style>
```

It works. But in my case I need to custom the `TabItem` So I used

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}" x:Key="HeaderStyle">
<Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/>
<Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
<Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
            <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" Height="23">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="25"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ContentPresenter ContentSource="Header" Margin="10,0,10,0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                    <ContentPresenter.Resources>
                        <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource Foreground}"/>
                            <Setter Property="Text"  Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Content.DataContext.ViewName}"></Setter>
                        </Style>
                    </ContentPresenter.Resources>
                </ContentPresenter>
                <Button Grid.Column="1" Height="15" Width="15" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                ...
</Style>
```

The problem now is the `Header` text is not shown. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try these:

`{Binding Path=Content.DataContext.ViewName, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type TabItem}}}`

or

`{Binding Path=DataContext.ViewName, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type TabItem}}}`

or

`{Binding Path=ViewName}`

Comment: It's not working, the `Content` is injected using Prism RegionManager.

Comment: @baozi Have you thought about using `HeaderTemplate`?